# WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)

Tags: java, excel

Here is my piece of code for reading file in `xlsx` and `xls` format

```
File customerTemplateFileObj = new File(customerTemplateFullPath);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(customerTemplateFileObj);

Workbook myWorkBook = null;
try {

    ***myWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);***
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int totalSheets = myWorkBook.getNumberOfSheets();
```

My code is working fine for `xls` format but for `xlsx` its stop at

```
myWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
```

without any Exception.

Comment: The OP posted but then deleted an answer suggesting that poi 1.14 and xmlbean2.0 jar got it working for them. This could be untrue, of course; we can't know why they deleted it.